# jQuery UI datepicker not accepting setDate or defaultDate on date range

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've got a problem with jQuery UI datepicker widget not accepting setDate or defaultDate parameters within the datepicker range.

Basically, the widget is initialized within the loop ( I'm looping through HTML div rows - theRow variable is a holder ), and this is the code that's running:

```
            $.each(theRow, function(index, val) {

                var self   = $(this),   
                fromDate   = new Date( self.find( ".days_from .hidden" ).html() )

                // init
                self.find( "#days_from" ).datepicker()
                self.find( "#days_to" ).datepicker()

               var dateFormat = "yy-mm-dd",
                  from = self.find( "#days_from" )
                    .datepicker({
                      stepMonths     : 1,
                      numberOfMonths : 1,
                      dateFormat     : "yy-mm-dd",
                      setDate        : fromDate,
                      minDate        : 0,
                      maxDate        : null
                    })
                    .on( "change", function() {
                      to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) )
                    }),
                  to = self.find( "#days_to" ).datepicker({
                    stepMonths     : 1,
                    dateFormat     : "yy-mm-dd",
                    numberOfMonths : 1
                  })

               function getDate( element ) {
                  var date;
                  try {
                    date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value )
                  } catch( error ) {
                    date = null;
                  }

                  return date;
               }                     

            })
```

What bothers me is that every other datepicker parameter is accepted and works perfectly, yet I cannot set an initial date. As mentioned, I've also tried using defaultDate option and had no luck as well.

I should mention that fromDate variable does return a proper date object with valid date in it.

If anyone could let me know where I went wrong, I would be highly grateful!

Comment: Hi, I had a similar problem once, Date format was not the same. My server side generated 14-08-2018 my client side format was 14/08/2018. Maybe console.log both to compare. I also had a situation with leading zeros I think or lack thereof for the month and or day value. Might need to see more to help further. Plunker or JSfiddle maybe, might even help you solve it?